# node -v: Command 'node' not found (but node is installed)

Tags: nodejs, npm

I am facing a strange issue while using nodejs. When i try to run `node -v` i get this:

```
Command 'node' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install nodejs
```

And when i try to run `npm -v` i get this:

```
Command 'npm' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install npm
```

But when i try to install node using nvm like this `nvm install v16.13.1` i get this:

```
v16.13.1 is already installed.
Now using node v16.13.1 (npm v8.1.2)
```

Now `node -v` and `npm -v` also work. This is happening everytime i restart my system. It is really annoying to run `nvm install v16.13.1` everytime is start my PC. any idea why this is happening?

Comment: maybe you are missing some config files for nvm, try re-installing nvm?

Comment: @Vthechamp re-installing nvm did not work. I have tried installing node version 12.12.0 it works fine. But when i switch my current node version to 16.13.1 and restart my system, the node version switched back to 12.12.0

Comment: did you install node from `apt`? if so, try removing the `apt` node and installing from nvm?

Comment: @Vthechamp i used to have node version installed from apt. but i have uninstalled it before installing node with nvm.